# React: How do I make child components rendered from an array update on parent change?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, webpack

I have it so multiple components get added and rendered upon a 'open' button click using a state array. I want to have it so that when I click a 'change' button, it'll change the state for the data of these components in the list and it should update, but it isn't.

It doesn't update the props in the child components in the array when I'm rendering multiple components using a state array. But it works when I just render duplicate components directly in the render function but this is not the functionality I want. I need to be able to add components on click, and also change the values of these child components with a different button click. How can I do this?

```
Main
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {renderWindow: false, windowArray: [], currentWindowData: "initial"}
    this.change= this.change.bind(this)
    this.open= this.open.bind(this)
}

open() {
   const newWindow = <Window key={shortid.generate()} body={this.state.currentWindowData}/>;
    this.setState({
        renderWindow: true, 
        windowArray: [newWindow, ...this.state.windowArray]
     })
}

change(val) {
    this.setState({currentWindowData: val});
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick = {() => this.open()}/>
        <button onClick = {() => this.change("ABC")}/>
        <button onClick = {() => this.change("XYZ")}/>
        {this.state.renderWindow ? this.state.windowArray : null}
      </div>
    )
}
```

In this window component, I just render this.props.body and even set up componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle hook just to be safe and render that data if I could receive it but it still doesn't update.

```
Window
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({bodyData: nextProps.body});
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.body}   
            {this.state.bodyData}
        </div> 
    );
}
```

But it works when I change the render function in main component and render a duplicate list of Window components there instead of from a state array. What gives?

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick = {() => this.open()}/>
        <button onClick = {() => this.change("ABC")}/>
        <button onClick = {() => this.change("XYZ")}/>
        {<Window key={shortid.generate()} body={this.state.currentWindowData}/>}
        {<Window key={shortid.generate()} body={this.state.currentWindowData}/>}
        {<Window key={shortid.generate()} body={this.state.currentWindowData}/>}

      </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the `Window` instances in your `open` method. You give the instance some properties, and save the instance in your state. When you rerender you then take the instances from your state and show them.

Note that you set the properties once, in your `open` method. At no later point in time are the props updated. If you want to update the properties when your `render` method is called, you have to either [clone your windows with new props](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) or store the properties you want in your state, and then generating the instances in your `render` method (as you do in your second example).

```js
open() {
  const id = shortid.generate();
  this.setState({
    // ...,
    windowIDs: [id, ...this.state.windowIDs]
  });
}

render() {
  const windows = this.state.windowIDs.map(
    id => <Window key={id} body={this.state.currentWindowData} />
  );
  return (
    <div>
      // ...
      { windows }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see now, thanks. So what did doing setState({currentWindowData: val}) in change() accomplish then? I thought that was what you needed to do to update the props? Or is it because I never re-rendered new Window components that that setState did not matter?

Comment: @SolidSnake Calling `setState` forces the element to rerender. The Window elements are never given new props however, since they are already instantiated. An elements properties are specified when it is created (e.g. in JSX), not when it is rendered.